# Group of orientation preserving homeomorphisms of circle $S^1$ acts transitively on the set of closed intervals of $S^1.$

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, geometric-topology

The closed intervals here mean the arcs including endpoints on the circle. I tried to do it by taking the inverse image of those two closed intervals from $S^1$ to its covering space $\mathbb{R}$ and then constructed a homeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}$ that takes these closed intervals to each other. But the issue is that while projecting it back to $S^1$, I am unable to ensure that this will result in a homeomorphism.

Any other approach is also welcome.

Comment: I assume that the induced action is via taking image: $\phi\circ I:=\phi(I)$? Then this is false, no proper subset of $S^1$ can be homeomorphic to $S^1$. Or are you saying that these intervals have to be proper subsets? What's the definition of interval in $S^1$ cause its confusing to me? As in: proper, infinite, connected and closed subsets of $S^1$?

Comment: @freakish That is likely what OP means, yes. The space of intervals in $S^1$ should be the same as the space of ordered pairs of distinct points.

Comment: So first of all you can assume that two such intervals have common end at $v=(1,0)$ and one is contained in another. This is due to applying rotations (which preserve orientation). Then you look at the preimage of the covering map in $[0,1)$ or $(0,1]$ depending on whether $0$ or $1$ is isolated, shrink one interval to another via $[0,1)\to[0,1)$ homeomorphism and recreate a homeomorphism $S^1\to S^1$ from that by applying the covering map.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Proper connected and closed sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $e : \mathbb{R} \to S^1, p(t) = e^{it}$, be the standard covering. An interval in $S^1$ is the image $I = e([a,b])$ of an interval $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $0 < b - a < 2\pi$. The restriction $e_I : [a,b] \to I$ of $e$ is a homeomorphism. Moreover we have $S^1 = I \cup I'$ with $I' = e([b,a+2\pi])$. Note that $I \cap I' = \{ e^{ia}, e^{ib} \}$.

Consider two intervals $I_k = e([a_k,b_k])$. Define "linear" homeomorphisms $u : [a_1,b_1] \to [a_2,b_2], u(t) = a_2 +\frac{b_2-a_2}{b_1-a_1}(t - a_1)$ and $u' : [b_1,a_1+2\pi] \to [b_2,a_2+2\pi], u'(t) = b_2 +\frac{a_2+2\pi-b_2}{a_1+2\pi-b_1}(t - b_1)$. These induce orientation preserving homeomorphisms $U : I_1 \to I_2$ and $U' : I'_1 \to I'_2$. Now $U$ and $U'$ can be pasted together to an orientation preserving homeomorphisms $h : S^1 = I_1 \cup I'_1 \to I_2 \cup I'_2 = S^1$. By construction $h(I_1) = I_2$.

Comment: Hi! Could you please tell me what the formal definition of an "orientation preserving" homeomorphism is?

Comment: @user56202 The concepts of *orientation* and *orientation preserving homeomorphism* are not that elementary that I could explain them in a comment. If you really want to understand them, you should consult a textbook dealing with manifolds. And you should  ask Sanjay Kapoor which definition he is using. Intuitively, an orientation preserving homeomorphism $h : S^1 \to S^1$ is going  *counterclockwise*, i.e. if you have two points $z_k = e^{it_k}$ with $0 \le t_1 < t_2 < 2\pi$ and $h(z_i) = e^{is_k}$ with $0 \le s_1, s_2 < 2\pi$, then $s_1 < s_2$.

Comment: If you know covering spaces, then you know that $h$ has a lift $\bar h : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ (which means $e \circ \bar h = h \circ e$). $h$ is orientation preserving iff $\bar h$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment! I do know a very tiny bit of covering spaces. So I imagine that once you know one lift of a homeomorphism $h$ is monotonic, you know that all lifts are monotonic? Also, about the iff condition; don't we need an extra hypothesis? I am taking a Dynamical Systems class, and altough my professor didn't define "orientation preserving homeomorphism", he did write the theorem: $f:S^1 \to S^1$ is orientation preserving homeomorphism iff $f$ has degree $1$ and any lift is strictly increasing.

Comment: In my professor's notation, the degree of $f$ is the integer $k$ such that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}: \overline{f}(x+1) = \overline{f}(x) + k$, where $\overline{f}$ is any lift of $f$.

Comment: @user56202 Your professor's definition / theorem has two ingredients: (1) Each continuous $f : S^1 \to S^1$ has a continuous lift $\bar f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$,   and any two lifts $\bar f_1, \bar f_2$ of $f$ differ by an integral multiple of $2\pi$ ($\bar f_2(x) - \bar f_1(x) = 2k\pi$  for all $x$ with some $k \in \mathbb Z$). This allows to define the *degree* for any $f$. (2) It is easy to see that if $f$ is a homeomorphism, then $\deg f = \pm 1$. We have $\deg f = +1$ iff $\bar f$ is strictly increasing,  $\deg f = -1$ iff $\bar f$ is strictly decreasing.

Comment: However, there are maps $f$ having degree $1$ but are no homeomorphisms, and there are maps $f$ having monotonic lifts although $\deg f \ne \pm1$ (e.g. $f(z) = z^2)$. Thus it is correct to state that a map $f$ is an orientation preserving homeomorphism iff $f$ has degree $1$ and any lift $\bar f$ is strictly increasing. If we already know that $f$ is a homeomorphism, then we can say that $f$ is orientation preserving iff $\deg f = +1$ iff $\bar f$ is strictly increasing.